# GADBannerView does not display properly when added off screen

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, admob

I'm adding GADBannerView off screen in a UIViewController by giving it the frame rect (0,self.frame.view.height,bannerWidth,bannerHeight), but when i try to pull it up to show only a small part shows. However when  use the rect (0,self.frame.view.height-bannerHeight,bannerWidth,bannerHeight) it works fine when I pull it up with animation by bannerHeight.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, print to NSLog your frames to determine the problem. Also try to move it by changing offset:

```
  UIView *bannerView = [UIView new]; // Here your banner view creation
  CGFloat bannerHeight = bannerView.frame.size.height;

  NSLog(@"bannerView frame before animation:%@", NSStringFromCGRect(bannerView.frame));
  [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{
    bannerView.frame = CGRectOffset(bannerView.frame, 0, -bannerHeight);
  } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    NSLog(@"bannerView frame after animation:%@", NSStringFromCGRect(bannerView.frame));
  }];
```

Show your code.

Comment: It seems like my UIView changes after load. I tried to play around in xcode and found if I uncheck resize view from xib of the viewcontroller it will work OK only on iPhone 4 inch but not in 3.5. Do you know why my view gets resized? does it have to do with autoresize parameters in xcode? Thank you.

Comment: Without code I can't tell anything. Your view will be resized, if you created a XIB for iPhone 3.5 inch and put there autoresizing masks and then run this XIB in iPhone 4 inch.